# Minimongo nested query embed documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor, real-time, minimongo

i want to search into an embed document in mongodb and return only what i'm looking for. 
Here's the document:

```
"_id" : "yH8HmCPz6H6E8Hinq",
"between" : [
    "4bgdLrztpqgwAkZP4",
    "9jZhXHjAkoY7mmX7B"
],
"messages" : [
    {
        "content" : "fdsqf",
        "user" : "4bgdLrztpqgwAkZP4",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2016-11-17T23:13:59.659Z"),
        "isSeen" : false,
        "sender" : "John doe",
        "receiver" : "Elen doe"
    },
    {
        "content" : "test",
        "user" : "9jZhXHjAkoY7mmX7B",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2016-11-20T11:42:42.893Z"),
        "isSeen" : false,
        "sender" : "Elen doe",
        "receiver" : "John doe"
    }
]
```

All what i want to have is "messages.isSeen" equals to false and receiver isn't Meteor.user().username.

And finally how to update that field to become true.

Hope someone can help ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm not entirely certain but does minimongo support $match and $project?

Comment: You can check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) answer

Comment: The probleme is i need to find the conversation by id then fetch for messages whom receiver is "John doe" for instance and then update the field. i've tried everything but nothing worked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `_id` in the query and `$set` in the update.

```
let id = "yH8HmCPz6H6E8Hinq";
let username = Meteor.user().username;
let query = { _id: id, messages: { $elemMatch: { isSeen: false, receiver: { $ne: username }}}};
Chat.update(query,{ $set: { "messages.$.isSeen": true }});
```

Comment: here's what the console say :
MongoError: cannot use the part (messages of messages.isSeen) to traverse the element...

Comment: I'im really sorry ! it's working like a charm ! Thank you very much sir ! THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
Chat.update({
  'messages.isSeen': false,          // isSeen is false
  'messages.receiver': {             // Receiver is
     $ne: Meteor.user().username     // not equal to Meteor.user().username
  }
}, {
  'messages.$isSeen': true           // Set isSeen to true
});
```

Comment: i need to find the conversation with the id first ! because it's a unique conversation between x and y ! and the find who receive the message, and then update the field isSeen.

Comment: I think just adding an `_id` field in the query will do the job. Don't you think?

Comment: Not working, i've tried everything ! it's really not working ! that's why i'm here ! kind of weird, because when i add anything else than the _id, it returns an empty object !